# My 98 Honda CRV power steering gets heavy after driving for a few minutes

Tags: honda, power-steering, crv

The weird thing is, though, that if I shut off the car and start it back up (even just 5 minutes later), everything goes back to normal for a while.

But once I am driving for say 10 - 15 minutes or longer, it starts making noise on turns and gets heavy.

I recently changed the pump to another used pump. This is the 3rd pump I have replaced in the last 2 weeks, could this be another bad pump (even though it doesn't leak fluid, as far as I have seen, and it doesn't have air bubbles in the reservoir)?

What are other things that could be causing this? I was reading up other causes of the general whining noise and some were suggesting replacing the pump inlet fitting O-ring, but I am not sure if that is the case here.

Is there any easy test I can do to see if it really is the pump inlet fitting O-ring in my case or if there is something else going on?

Comment: Is there any reason it couldn't be the rack itself?

Comment: You mean the rack and pinion? I just changed that, so theoretically, it shouldn't be that.

Comment: How did you go about bleeding the pump after isntallation?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like air in the system. It is the most common cause of this symptom. Leaks in the pump to reservoir hose or pump inlet o-ring fitting are common. Even if you do not see bubbles.